# Javascript in table gives error 'This content cannot be displayed in a frame' in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using Wordpress and have a simple HTML table in a post. I use javascript to make all of the row clickable to a URL. Some clients report an error using Internet Explorer, 'This content cannot be displayed in a frame'. I need 2 things:

1. The link to open in a new tab (it currently opens in the same window)
2. To remove this error (even the content below gives the error).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
<table class="mytable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Publisher</th>
<th>ISBN</th>
</tr>
<tr onclick="document.location = 'http://amazon.com/dp/1234567890';">
<td><strong><em>Book A</em></strong></td>
<td>rrr</td>
<td>hhh</td>
<td>123414</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt" onclick="document.location = 'http://amazon.com/s?index=books&amp;field-author=fred';">
<td><strong><em>Book B</em></strong></td>
<td>VVV</td>
<td>AAA</td>
<td>n/a</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if you have control over the html, would it not be simpler to use anchors? you can then use the target attribute to open in a new window/tab.

Comment: Nick, I need the whole row clickable, that's why I'm using this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to do this using anchors, however it would require one for each column in each row and I guess your not up for that!

I cant seem to replicate the error you're getting, I guess your using a different version of IE to me.

Using the TR onclick event does seem to be the easiest method.

As you want the link to open in a new window or tab (its not really in your control as it depends on how the clients browser is configured) you can use window.open() instead of changing window.location like you are currently.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function navigate(url) {
  window.open(url);
}
</script>
```

Add something along those lines to the head of your page.

```
<tr onclick="navigate('where.you/want-to-go');">
```

And you'll be able to use it like that. I don't know if this will trigger any pop-up blocker type things but for my tests it opened a new tab.

The window.open function can take some extra arguments to try to force new tabs or windows etc but don't know how many browsers what and how well it works.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll try that. You are right, less code is better than repeating hyperlinks on each cell. I'm just a little unsure if this will cure the IE error. For information this occurred in version 9 on Win 7. I'll give your code a try.

Comment: I used IE9 on Win7 too, maybe my test page is missing something that yours has that is causing the issue. I didn't exactly say it was better, just easier. Using anchors does mean a little more work on your part but will get you a more compatible and reliable end result (no requirement for javascript).